Rendering Parameter is not getting serialized to Layout service
I have a checkbox as a rendering parameter for a rendering. But I am not getting it in layout service response when its unchecked. However, if its checked I get it inside layout service response as 1.
When unchecked, I should get it as 0 inside "params". But "params" is not at all there.
Anyone pls clarify this. Thanks.

This is the expected behaviour. The rendering paramaters are read from the Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingParameters class where the list of values are set using below code.
 public RenderingParameters(string parametersAsQueryString) => this.Values = parametersAsQueryString.ToDictionary((IEqualityComparer<string>) StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Inside the above ToDictionary method, it skips the empty value from the list of key value pair. Foreg. when the rendering params contains the value as IsCategory&DynamicPlaceholderId=1 inside the raw values, this method will create a dictionary with only one key as DynamicPlaceholderId, ignoring the empty key IsCategory. IsCategory is the checkbox field available as a rendering parameter on the rendering.
Thus all the empty values in the rendering parameters are skipped therefore it is required to add a null check for the rendering param key on the JSS application.
Note: This is the same behaviour for MVC as well, wherein when you try to read IsCategory rendering parameter using below code, it returns null instead of '0' or 'false'.
RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["IsCategory"]

Hope this helps!!!

Thank you. It helps. :)

@RashmiRanjan Glad it helped!!!
